# jQuery Canvas Pause and Start listener based on HasClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I'm having problems setting up a listener that will pause and start a canvas animation based on HasClass. Basically I want the animation to pause when a `<a href="#">` has a certain class. Using jQuery I know enough how to add and remove but not tie it all together so they work together nicely. This is a little out of my comfort zone and appreciate any help.

Below is my simple HTML code:

```
<a id="eY" href="#" class="paused">
    <span class="pause">Pause</span>
    <span class="resume">Resume</span>
</a>
<canvas id="world"> </canvas>
```

Below is my JavaScript:

```
jQuery(function($) {

    !+-+-+!+-+-+!+-+-+!+-+-+!+-+-+!+-+-+!+-+-+!+-+-+!
function(d, w){
    var FPS = 30;
    var F = 300;
    var N = 3;
    var VERTEX_MAX = 10;
    var TRAIL_QUALITY = 4000;
    var mu = 0.5;
    var bmRandom = function(mu, sigma){
        var x, y, r, tmp=null, tmp2;
        return function(){
            if(tmp !== null){
                tmp2 = tmp;
                tmp = null;
                return y*tmp2+mu;
            }
            do{
                x = Math.random()*2-1;
                y = Math.random()*2-1;
                r = x*x+y*y;
            }while(r>=1);
            tmp = sigma*Math.sqrt(-2*Math.log(r)/r);
            return x*tmp+mu;
        };
    };
    pointCopy = function(src, dst){
        dst.x = src.x;
        dst.y = src.y;
        dst.z = src.z;
        return dst;
    };
    Trail = function(pos, t, color_f){
        this.pos={x:0,y:0,z:0};
        this.start={x:0,y:0,z:0};
        this.goal={x:0,y:0,z:0};
        this.anchor_1={x:0,y:0,z:0};
        this.anchor_2={x:0,y:0,z:0};
        this.start_time = 0;
        this.take_time = 1;
        this.vertexes = [];
        this.anchors_1 = [];
        this.anchors_2 = [];
        this.color_f = color_f;
        pointCopy(pos, this.pos);
        pointCopy(pos, this.start);
        pointCopy(pos, this.goal);
        this.setNextGoal(t);
    };
    Trail.prototype.setNextGoal = function(t, target){
        pointCopy(this.goal, this.start);
        this.anchor_1.x = this.start.x+(this.start.x-this.anchor_2.x)*mu;
        this.anchor_1.y = this.start.y+(this.start.y-this.anchor_2.y)*mu;
        this.anchor_1.z = this.start.z+(this.start.z-this.anchor_2.z)*mu;
        if(target){
            this.anchor_2.x = (this.anchor_1.x+target.x)/2+myrand();
            this.anchor_2.y = (this.anchor_1.y+target.y)/2+myrand();
            this.anchor_2.z = (this.anchor_1.z+target.z)/2+myrand();
            this.goal.x = target.x;
            this.goal.y = target.y;
            this.goal.z = target.z;
        }else{
            this.anchor_2.x = this.anchor_1.x+myrand();
            this.anchor_2.y = this.anchor_1.y+myrand();
            this.anchor_2.z = this.anchor_1.z+myrand();
            this.goal.x = this.anchor_2.x+myrand();
            this.goal.y = this.anchor_2.y+myrand();
            this.goal.z = this.anchor_2.z+myrand();
        }
        this.start_time = t;
        this.take_time = 200+Math.random()*200;
        this.vertexes.push(pointCopy(this.start, {x:0,y:0,z:0}));
        this.anchors_1.push(pointCopy(this.anchor_1, {x:0,y:0,z:0}));
        this.anchors_2.push(pointCopy(this.anchor_2, {x:0,y:0,z:0}));
        if(this.vertexes.length > VERTEX_MAX){
            this.vertexes.splice(0,this.vertexes.length-VERTEX_MAX);
            this.anchors_1.splice(0,this.anchors_1.length-VERTEX_MAX);
            this.anchors_2.splice(0,this.anchors_2.length-VERTEX_MAX);
        }
    };
    Trail.prototype.update = function(t, target){
        bezier3(
            t-this.start_time,
            this.start,
            this.anchor_1,
            this.anchor_2,
            this.goal,
            this.take_time,
            this.pos
            );
        if(t-this.start_time > this.take_time){
            this.setNextGoal(this.start_time+this.take_time, target);
            this.update(t, target);
        }
    };
    Trail.prototype.draw = function(ctx, camera, t){
        var i, dz, dt, ddt, rt, a, v={x:0, y:0, z:0};
        var ps = {x:0, y:0};
        ctx.beginPath();
        if(perspective(this.vertexes[0], camera, ps)){
            ctx.moveTo(ps.x, ps.y);
        }
        var x0 = ps.x;
        rt = (t-this.start_time)/this.take_time;
        for(i=1; i<this.vertexes.length; i++){
            ddt = 0.01;
            for(dt=0; dt<1; dt+=ddt){
                bezier3(dt,
                        this.vertexes[i-1],
                        this.anchors_1[i-1],
                        this.anchors_2[i-1],
                        this.vertexes[i],
                        1,
                        v);
                if(perspective(v, camera, ps)){
                    dz = v.z-camera.z;
                    a = 1-(this.vertexes.length-i+1-dt+rt)/VERTEX_MAX;
                    this.color_f(ctx, a, dz);
                    ctx.lineTo(ps.x, ps.y);
                    ctx.stroke();
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.moveTo(ps.x, ps.y);
                    ddt = dz/TRAIL_QUALITY+0.01;
                }
            }
        }
        ddt = 0.01;
        for(dt=0; dt<rt; dt+=ddt){
            bezier3(dt,
                    this.start,
                    this.anchor_1,
                    this.anchor_2,
                    this.goal,
                    1,
                    v);
            if(perspective(v, camera, ps)){
                dz = v.z-camera.z;
                a = 1-(1-dt+rt)/VERTEX_MAX;
                this.color_f(ctx, a, dz);
                ctx.lineTo(ps.x, ps.y);
                ctx.stroke();
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(ps.x, ps.y);
                ddt = dz/TRAIL_QUALITY+0.01;
            }
        }
        if(perspective(this.pos, camera, ps)){
            dz = this.pos.z-camera.z;
            a = 1-1/VERTEX_MAX;
            this.color_f(ctx, a, dz);
            ctx.lineTo(ps.x, ps.y);
            ctx.stroke();
        }
    };
    bezier3 = function(t, a, b, c, d, e, dst){
        t /= e;
        dst.x =
            a.x*(1-t)*(1-t)*(1-t)+
            b.x*3*t*(1-t)*(1-t)+
            c.x*3*t*t*(1-t)+
            d.x*t*t*t;
        dst.y =
            a.y*(1-t)*(1-t)*(1-t)+
            b.y*3*t*(1-t)*(1-t)+
            c.y*3*t*t*(1-t)+
            d.y*t*t*t;
        dst.z =
            a.z*(1-t)*(1-t)*(1-t)+
            b.z*3*t*(1-t)*(1-t)+
            c.z*3*t*t*(1-t)+
            d.z*t*t*t;
    };
    perspective = function(point, camera, dst){
        var dx = point.x-camera.x;
        var dy = point.y-camera.y;
        var dz = point.z-camera.z;
        if(dz > 0){
            dst.x = F*dx/dz;
            dst.y = F*dy/dz;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    };
    updateScene = function(ctx){
        var i, goal;
        time_now = new Date().getTime();
        var time_d = time_now-time_pre;
        trails[0].update(time_now);
        for(i=1; i<trails.length; i++){
            trails[i].update(time_now, trails[i-1].pos);
        }
        camera.x += (trails[0].pos.x-camera.x)*0.0005*time_d;
        camera.y += (trails[0].pos.y-camera.y)*0.0005*time_d;
        camera.z += (trails[0].pos.z-camera.z-100)*0.0005*time_d;
        time_pre = time_now;
    };
    drawScene = function(ctx){
        var i;
        ctx.clearRect(-canvas.width/2, -canvas.height/2, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        for(i=0; i<trails.length; i++){
            trails[i].draw(ctx, camera, time_now);
        }
    };
    var myrand = bmRandom(0,20);
    var canvas = d.getElementById("world");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var trails = [];
    var i;
    var time_now = new Date().getTime();
    var time_pre = time_now;
    var camera = {x:0, y:0, z:-200};
    for(i=0; i<N; i++){
        trails.push(new Trail({x:myrand(), y:myrand(), z:myrand()},
                              time_now,
                              function(a,z){return "#FFFFFF";}));
    }
    for(i=0; i<N; i++){
        switch(i%3){
            case 0:
                trails[i].color_f=function(ctx, a, dz){
                    var b = dz<10?0:a*F/dz;
                    b = (b>1?1:b)*(dz<30?(dz-10)/20:1);
                    ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(230,230,230,"+b+")";
                    ctx.lineWidth = F/dz;
                    ctx.lineCap = b>0.8?"round":"butt";
                };
                break;
            case 1:
                trails[i].color_f=function(ctx, a, dz){
                    var b = dz<10?0:a*F/dz;
                    b = (b>1?1:b)*(dz<30?(dz-10)/20:1);
                    ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(230, 230,230,"+b+")";
                    ctx.lineWidth = F/dz;
                    ctx.lineCap = b>0.8?"round":"butt";
                };
                break;
            default:
                trails[i].color_f=function(ctx, a, dz){
                    var b = dz<10?0:a*F/dz;
                    b = (b>1?1:b)*(dz<30?(dz-10)/20:1);
                    ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(132,232,251,"+b+")";
                    ctx.lineWidth = F/dz;
                    ctx.lineCap = b>0.8?"round":"butt";
                };
                break;
        }
    }
    var loop = function(){
        canvas.width = w.innerWidth;
        canvas.height = w.innerHeight;
        ctx.translate(canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2);
        updateScene();
        drawScene(ctx);
        w.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    }
    loop();
    }(document, window);

    $("#eY").click(function(){
        $("#eY").toggleClass("start");
    });    
});
```

And here you can see my [JsFiddle to make things easier](https://jsfiddle.net/n32ch2ye/16/). The other solution I've thought about is using CSS to hide the canvas but am I right in saying using display:none; on a canvas doesn't stop the calculations which effectively will put load on the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hiding the canvas will only hide the element itself, but it won't stop the loop from running. You need something to tell the animation loop to stop from inside it. You can for example use a boolean flag.

Example:

```
var isRunning = true;                  // this will keep animation running or stop it
var loop = function(){
    canvas.width = w.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = w.innerHeight;
    ctx.translate(canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2);
    updateScene();
    drawScene(ctx);
    if (isRunning) w.requestAnimationFrame(loop);  // check if we're running...
}
loop();

// helper function to restart the loop when toggled from not running, to running    
function toggle() {
    isRunning = !isRunning;
    if (isRunning) loop();  // if new status is running, start loop
};

// move this inside the animation scope so we have access to the loop etc.
$("#eY").click(function(){
    $("#eY").toggleClass("start");
    toggle();                      // also call this
});
```

**[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/fhq5wgqa/)**

There may be other issues, I only addressed this one. Just open new question if there should be.

Off-topic: cool animation, reminds me of TrapCode's Strokes in AE/Combustion.

Comment: Hi Ken and thanks for the reply. Because the nature of the design I'd like a listener toggle on HasClass, so 'if HasClass toggle' I'm poor at JavaScript is this doable and if so, how. The idea behind this method is that when I click a menu element, it adds pause to an element and then a listener pauses the animation. And primary the reason I thought hasclass would be better since it'll work outside the scope as you put it.

Comment: @bybe you could expose the toggle flag to the outside by adding it as a property on the object. The problem here is that the scope here is "closed", there is no access from the outside. You have to expose methods/properties on it but it can be challenging with the pattern (function(args) {})(args);

Comment: Cheers Ken, using the code you provided I was able to make a solution that worked for me!